# How to chain chain Akka messages in Play controller?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

In my controller I have a method that calls passes a message to an actor A, receives the response from A, passes that response to actor B and then finally renders the response.

The code looks like this

```
def abc(userId: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async(implicit request => {
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds
(AActor ? ARequest(userId)).mapTo[AResponse].map { aResponse =>
      aResponse.ar match {
        case Some(x) => {
          ((BActor ? BRequest(x)).mapTo[BResponse].map { bResponse =>
            (bResponse.br).map(o => Ok(Json.toJson(o))).getOrElse(BadRequest("not found"))
      })
    }
    case None => BadRequest(Messages("not found"))
  }
}
}
```

I get the following error message

`Found: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] Required: play.api.mvc.Result`

I understand that in case of `Some(x)` it expect the function to return a result, but if I want to chain the message how should I go about it ?

Thanks,

Utsav

Comment: Not really an answer but... do you really need an actor system for that? I mean unless you're forced to use those akka actors in order to do what you have to, your case looks more like you would just need a few functions returning `Future`s and just chain them. `akka` actors are, usually, best used in a `fire-and-forget` fashion.

Comment: Anyways... You may want to try using a for comprehension. Something like https://gist.github.com/mfirry/4dd623fb3e3a2ec9371ece5664df72ae

Comment: Need `for` or `flapMap` on `Future` (not specific to Play or Akka)